# Relationship between gamma and theta

Tags: option-pricing, greeks

I have read somewhere the following statements, which I have observed to be true most of the time. I want to know how accurate they are mathematically, and how to prove them?

> $\Gamma > 0$ is a good position to be in, and therefore you have to pay a premium for it, on the other hand $\Gamma < 0$ is a bad position to be in so you get paid premium for it.

> $\theta$ and $\Gamma$ have an opposite relationship i.e. if, let's say $\theta$ is positive, then $\Gamma$ will be negative and vice-versa. $\theta$ is like the rent you pay to be long $\Gamma$

Are these statements model-free i.e. can they be proven, without assuming anything about the stochastic process that the underlying stock price follows. Is this it, or is there any deeper relationship between $\theta$ and $\Gamma$?

Comment: These statements are not model-free. They can be made model free if you include other convexity terms. Even in a Black-Scholes setting the statement above is not strictly correct since the risk-free rate $r$ and dividends are not taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you please elaborate on your arguments?